# Connect 12 V DC sensor to Arduino Uno using TTL RS485

Tags: arduino-uno, rs485, modbus

I'm trying to connect an Arduino Uno with a [BGT PM2510 sensor](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/BGT-PM2510-Industrial-Dust-Particle-PM2_62480865889.html) (which uses 7-12 V DC) by using a [UART TTL to RS485 Two-way Converter](https://www.elecrow.com/uart-ttl-to-rs485-twoway-converter-p-1545.html).

The only thing I wonder about is: can the sensor damage the MCU?

According to the information on the 12 V sensor, it says:

`Output signal: RS485 (Modbus protocol)`. I did measurements on the A & B ports of that sensor; the multimeter showed 3.3 V.

**My question is, can the sensor damage the MCU? I intend to connect the Arduino and sensor as in the diagram below**:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You should be fine.

RS-485 does specify signal levels of ±1.5 V to ±5 V, but even so, and even when the sensor would misbehave or when the common mode voltage is low or high, there is still the TTL-to-RS485 converter in the middle that has 5 V TTL logic on the Arduino side.

As long as the TTL-to-RS485 converter is properly connected to the Arduino and working as it should, the Arduino is safe.